# Views that behave as lightbox or standalone depending on context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

Let's say we have three views: **A**, **B** and **X**. The urls for these are /A, /B and /X.

**A** and **B** both contain a link pointing to **X**. When clicked, **X** renders as a lightbox on top of **A** or **B**, and the url is updated.

On the other hand, when directly entering that url (i.e. by manually entering it into the browser), the view **X** is shown as a standalone page.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the container and content of **X** stays the same across both states (lightbox & standalone).

The main question is how to resolve this issue correctly in terms of routes and directives.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.